# c++ Values in a map of structures does are changing in a hidden way

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary

In my code, I have the following section:

```
void do_avg(){
  std::map<int,hqs>::iterator it = vals.begin();
  while(it != vals.end()){
    int q = (*it).first;
    hqs val = (*it++).second;
    val.hs = 0;
    printf("%i: %f\n",q,val.hs);
  }
  it = vals.begin();
  while (it != vals.end()){
    int q = (*it).first;
    hqs val = (*it++).second;
    printf("%i: %f\n",q,val.hs);
  }
}
```

prints:

```
0: 0.000000
1: 0.000000
2: 0.000000
4: 0.000000
5: 0.000000
8: 0.000000
9: 0.000000
10: 0.000000
13: 0.000000
0: 14.713500
1: 0.050911
2: 0.006717
4: 0.074708
5: 0.020139
8: 0.049042
9: 0.033990
10: 0.033952
13: 0.005567
```

_some definitions:
`vals` is defined as:

```
std::map<int, hqs> vals;
```

and `hqs` is a structure:

```
typedef struct{
        short q;
        double hs;
        std::vector <double> ah;
        double error;
        short counter;
}hqs;
```

the header of the code also includes:

```
#include <map>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>

void do_avg();
```

For some reason, the values of val.hs are changed between the first and second run. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

OK, since you're asking what's "easiest" despite two good answers, perhaps you mean "what's easiest to read" -- a great point, so let's try a rewrite:

```
void do_avg()
{
  typedef std::map<int,hqs>::iterator hqs_map_it;

  // Assign
  for (hqs_map_it it = vals.begin(), end = vals.end(); it != end; ++it)
  {
    it->second = 0;
    printf("%i: %f\n", it->first, it->second);
  }

  // Check
  for (hqs_map_it it = vals.begin(), end = vals.end(); it != end; ++it)
  {
    printf("%i: %f\n", it->first, it->second);
  }
}
```

If you really do want to use named variables in the loop, use references:

```
  for (hqs_map_it it = vals.begin(), end = vals.end(); it != end; ++it)
  {
    const int & q = it->first;
    hqs     & val = it->second;
    val.hs = 0; // now using the reference to update the map's value!
    printf("%i: %f\n", q, val);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    val.hs = 0; -----------------------> You are printing this
    printf("%i: %f\n",q,val.hs);
```

In the first run you are explicitly setting the variable to zero and printing it.

[EDIT] : As your comment states you are trying to alter the contents of the map and set it to 0. So here is the explanation of why it doesn't work:

By your first statement you are not changing the contents of the map et all.
`val` is just a copy of the content inside the  map. Changing it does not affect the values inside the map.

```
hqs val = (*it++).second;
```

Just assigns the value to a local variable `val` and you print that value. The contents of the map never got altered. To modify the content inside the map you must modify

```
(*it++).second.hs
```

and not a copy of it.

Comment: I know, I want them to be 0, but why doesn't they stay 0? (The problem started when I realized that they don't stay 0).

Comment: ...and changing val.hs affects only val, not the data that's in the map.  val is a copy of one of your map values.

Answer (score 0):

No need for pointer. Do this

```
(*it++).second.hs = 0;
```

instead of this

```
hqs val = (*it++).second;
val.hs = 0;
```

As you already know, you were changing a copy of the data in the map.

Comment: I just did, I'm not sure which way is more easy for me to follow